# Converting US date to UK format in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am currently pulling out  US date from another spreadsheet using the following formula

```
=LEFT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'Token Report 2'!A:C,2,FALSE),""),16)
```

which gets me the following:

```
04/23/2014 23:04
```

from

```
04/23/2014 23:04 CDT
```

How do I get it to convert it to a UK date/time and get it to register with Excel?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to convert CDT time to GMT or do you want to format the value to show with your regional settings? And what do you mean by `get it to register with Excel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 5 hours to go from CDT to GMT.

`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,16))+5/24`, where `A1' hold the text, will give you the correct date and time value.  You'll need to format the cell to display properly as a date and time, or convert it to text explicitly (not usually recommended).

So `=VALUE(LEFT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'Token Report 2'!A:C,2,FALSE),""),16))+5/24`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel's text-to-column function. I'm copying the answer from [here](https://purplecomputing.com/tech-how-to/microsoft-office/convert-us-dates-to-uk-excel/)

1. Paste the dates into a column in a new Excel spreadsheet
2. Select the whole column
3. Select the Data menu > Text to Columns
4. Choose “Delimited” and click next
5. Untick all Delimiters and click next
6. Select the dropdown menu format “Date: MDY” and click Finish